# How to show the info page into new "layer"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a contact link on my website and i don't want to add the simple hyperlink to it, because my contact info is about 5-6 lines of text.

After click I want it appear on the page I clicked the link, but in something like window (NO POPUP) - just on a higher layer with a close button. I've made it already with Jquery.animate, that the facebook like button was coming from behind the screen - but now I want something different : ].

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different?

try this:

```
<button onclick="alert('Address: blah blah Phone: 00blah')">Contact Info</button>
```

just kidding :) , you might check jquery ui dialog box:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

for something "different"

Comment: jquery ui dialog box is exactly main point - that's "different" : ) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is HTML:

```
<a id="mci">My Contact Info</a>

<div id="info_box">
      <h1>This is contact info box</h1>
      <a id="info_box_close">Close</a>    
</div>
```

This is CSS:

```
#info_box { 
display:none;
 position:fixed;  
 height:300px;  
 width:300px;  
 background:#EEEEEE;  
 left: 50px;
 top: 50px;
 z-index:100;
 margin-left: 15px; }

#info_box_close {
 font-size:20px;  
 right:5px;  
 top:5px;  
 position:absolute;  
 color:red;  
 font-weight:bold;      
}
```

And, finaly, Jquery:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready( function() {

     $('#mci').click( function() {  
            $('#info_box').fadeIn("slow");
     });

     $('#info_box_close').click( function() {            
           $('#info_box').fadeOut("slow");
     });

 });
 </script>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/wJzTh/